# "I sat a hundred evenings there"

Tags: past-tense, conjugations

I'm translating a piece of literature that describes the writer's childhood memory of a cake shop where he sat many times with his granddad. I'm not sure if my translation gives back what he means:
"The Blue Bird cake shop where I sat a hundred evenings with my grandfather."

So there were about a hundred different evenings that he spent at this cake shop with his granddad.

Am I using the right tense? It doesn't sound outright wrong to me, but perhaps I'm confusing myself.

Comment: It's fine, grammatically, but we just would probably use: many, many evenings. A hundred sounds too specific.

Comment: This is completely fine. I use this phrase more than a bit myself to communicate the same feeling.

Comment: I would find "_on_ a hundred evenings" a bit more idiomatic.

Comment: I would find *...where I **spent** a hundred evenings* far more idiomatic. Native speakers don't very often adverbially modify ***to sit*** by a time duration without a preposition. And to be honest, I'm not all that keen on either ***on, for*** or ***over*** in this exact context. Stylistically speaking I'd say it's better to change the actual verb from ***sat*** to something like ***spent*** that doesn't need a preposition anyway. Essentially, this has no implications for the actual *meaning.*

Comment: I really like "where I sat a hundred evenings." It reminds me of Dylan's 'Frankie Lee and Judas Priest'. (Or maybe of [Heraclitus](https://www.johnderbyshire.com/Readings/heraclitus.html).) "spent" is more conventional though.

Comment: It's not a sentence, so no, it isn't correct. It's just a noun clause. Consider: "*The Blue Bird Cake Shop **was** where I sat...*"

Comment: It's not a sentence, so the full stop should not be part of it. You could have *"The Blue Bird cake shop, where I sat a hundred evenings with my grandfather, was in a lane behind the Town Hall."*

Comment: @Lambie but then you lose the meter *...SAT-a HUNdred EV'nings...* is far superior in my inner monologue. I would probably change from Cake shop to Bakery for allegory and meter (and you don't lose that much meaning) - but it does depend on the original work. I'd evaluate it at least. And I would change the verb to "spent". You spend an evening. You don't sit it. (course you can sit also, but to me it just sounds better)

Comment: @gotube The *Blue Cake Shop* **was** where I sat. is a sentence. Not a noun clause.

Comment: In some sense, you'll need to provide the original to know if you are capturing the original correctly.

Comment: It's poetic. It conveys a myriad scenes in one [not quite a] sentence. Frankly, I don't care if it's not a perfectly-cast sentence in & of itself. It *feels*. <-That, quite intentionally wasn't a sentence either. To swap 'sat' for 'spent' or similar would discard meaning & intent; it would reduce it to the mundane, whereas 'sat' elevates the mundane.

Comment: The sentence as written conveys a slight sense of archaic, or perhaps even anachronistic. A brief description of a years'-long-past habit being brought to modern recollection. [It doesn't make me think Dostoyevsky just walked in the room, it's not brutally archaic, it's just … ermm… quaint (& not in a bad way)] Werther's originals, or Hovis [for the Brits who remember those ads]

Comment: @Lambie Yes, and that's not what it says in the OP. My version with "was" is a suggestion, which is why I said "Consider:..." before it

Comment: Definitely in a poetic/lyrical register. cf. [I've laid this island sun a 1000 times](https://www.musixmatch.com/lyrics/The-Breeders/Off-You)

Answer (score 16):

Yes, I see no problem with that interpretation.

The value "a hundred" is likely to be understood as "an unspecified large number"

Answer (score 8):

That sounds great to me.  Very florid and poetic, if that’s the effect you’re going for.  The tense is fine; standard English doesn’t distinguish the imperfect aspect the way some other languages do.  “I **used to** sit”  might make it slightly less ambiguous that the narrator is talking about a recurring or habitual former action, and “**over** a hundred evenings” slightly more explicit that we’re talking about many different evenings rather than one evening that felt like a hundred, but I think the meaning is perfectly clear as it is.

One minor nit: “where I sat a hundred evenings ...” is a non-restrictive clause.  There isn’t some other Blue Bird cake shop the audience might have in mind where he didn’t sit a hundred evenings with his grandfather.  So, in formal written English, there should be a comma before the relative clause: “The Blue Bird cake shop, where I sat a hundred evenings with my grandfather.”

The one reason I can think of that you might prefer a different construction is if if you want the narrator to sound a little less formal.  Personally, though, I think it works well to say this in a way that stands out a bit. My advice would be not to change this turn of phrase into something more humdrum.

Comment: It's not grammatically incorrect to use a restrictive clause for something that has already been uniquely defined.

Answer (score 2):

To me, it sounds fine. Some people may not understand it instantly, but overall I feel as if it sounds natural if it is meant to sound more ‘poetic’

Answer (score 0):

*Sit* can take a direct object, which gives somewhat different more specific [meanings](https://www.lexico.com/definition/sit). For example "to sit nine subjects at an exam", "to sit a horse", "a table sitting 6 people". So to some readers "where I sat a hundred evenings" becomes ambiguous or confusing at first (subconscious) parse; that is then discarded and reinterpreted as verb + adverb. Perhaps that is what elicits some sense of discomfort for you.